# Cockroach-DB - wrong calculation of date difference

Tags: date, cockroachdb

I'm using CockroachDB **v20.1.1** and getting wrong results for date calculations:

Example:

$> select '2021-10-28'::date - interval '1 years'; ==>  2020-10-28 00:00:00 is correct

$> select '2021-10-29'::date - interval '1 years'; ==> **2019**-10-30 00:00:00 is WRONG

What am I doing wrong...?
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was a bug in v20.1.1: https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pull/56667. It's fixed in subsequent releases. At this point, since [v20.1 is almost at EOL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/release-support-policy.html#current-supported-releases), it'd be best for you to [upgrade to v20.2](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/upgrade-cockroach-version) or later.